# Algebras such that the tensor product with any Noetherian algebra is Noetherian

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, nonnoetherian, noetherian

Let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative unital ring. It is generally speaking not true that the tensor product of two Noetherian $R$-algebras is Noetherian (e.g. take $R$ to be a field, and consider the tensor square of some crazy field extension).

What is true is that a tensor product of a finite type $R$-algebra and a Noetherian $R$-algebra is Noetherian. It is not true, however, that an $R$-algebra whose tensor product with any Noetherian $R$-algebra is Noetherian has to be of finite type (consider the power series ring, for example). What is the name for the class of $R$-algebras that have this property?

Comment: I don't think power series algebras have the property you claim. On the other hand, all *localizations* of finitely generated algebras do.

Comment: I am not aware of even one example of a noetherian ring R, and two noetherian R-algebras A,B such that $A\otimes_R B$ is noetherian, in which not at least one of A,B is essentially of finite type over R.

Comment: Meta discussion here:  https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-new-users

Answer (score 3):

A (not necessarily commutative) algebra $A$ over a commutative noetherian ring $R$ is called *strongly noetherian* if for every noetherian $R$-algebra $R'$ the extension $A \otimes_R R'$ is noetherian. See [this paper of Artin, Small, and Zhang](https://doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1999.7997) for a reference. This property has also been discussed [in this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108183/strongly-noetherian-property-when-is-the-tensor-a-otimes-kb-noetherian-for).

This is an issue of importance in noncommutative algebra, where there exist finitely generated noetherian algebras that do not remain noetherian after extending the base field. (There is a well-known [example of this phenomenon due to Resco and Small](https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/25.6.549).) But as your question indicates, it is already an interesting property to consider for commutative algebras.